php fpm + apache on ubuntu 22.04.3 don't interpret php code
I installed php fpm on ubuntu, and enabled the proxy_fcgi module.  I created a test file that just calls phpinfo, but since I switched to php fpm, when I hit the page, instead of executing the php code, apache just returns a page that contains the php source.
I don't find any error in the logs.  I also tried to enable a bunch of modules that I would find on internet docs, but it didn't change anything.
I'll provide the relevant config files I modified and relevant commands below.  I also verified the fpm server is running, and that the unix socket to communicate with it exists.
Any idea what I did wrong?
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler “proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/”
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
access_compat.load  autoindex.conf  filter.load       proxy_fcgi.load
alias.conf          autoindex.load  mime.conf         proxy_http.load
alias.load          deflate.conf    mime.load         reqtimeout.conf
auth_basic.load     deflate.load    mpm_event.conf    reqtimeout.load
authn_core.load     dir.conf        mpm_event.load    setenvif.conf
authn_file.load     dir.load        negotiation.conf  setenvif.load
authz_core.load     env.load        negotiation.load  status.conf
authz_host.load     fcgid.conf      proxy.conf        status.load
authz_user.load     fcgid.load      proxy.load
$ cat /etc/ec2_version 
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
# systemctl restart php8.1-fpm && systemctl restart apache2
# tail -n 3 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Fri Apr 26 13:58:35.327295 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31924:tid 281446406930464] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Apr 26 13:58:35.442722 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32194:tid 261126812663840] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 26 13:58:35.442845 2024] [core:notice] [pid 32194:tid 261126812663840] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
# ps aux | fgrep fpm
root 31905 0.0 1.0 202252 19948 ? Ss 13:35 0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 31907 0.0 0.4 202828 9512 ? S 13:35 0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 31908 0.0 0.4 202828 9512 ? S 13:35 0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root 32413 0.0 0.0 3300 1792 pts/3 S+ 14:34 0:00 grep -F --color=auto fpm

I hit the phpinfo.php page and expected to see the details of the php environment.  Instead I got the source code of the page:
$ ls -l /var/www/html/phpinfo.php 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 20 Mar 30 12:02 /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
$ cat /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
$ ls -H -l /run/php/php-fpm.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Apr 28 16:49 /run/php/php-fpm.sock
$ curl http://localhost/phpinfo.php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>


Does this answer your question? Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it

Unfortunately, no, this one isn't about php fpm, it's about mod_php.  But thanks for the suggestion.

What else did you try? Is FPM running after all?

I tried to enable a bunch of modules that I would find on internet docs, but it didn't change anything.  I verified, and yes, it's running:
ps aux | fgrep fpm
root       31905  0.0  1.0 202252 19948 ?        Ss   13:35   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data   31907  0.0  0.4 202828  9512 ?        S    13:35   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data   31908  0.0  0.4 202828  9512 ?        S    13:35   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root       32413  0.0  0.0   3300  1792 pts/3    S+   14:34   0:00 grep -F --color=auto fpm

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Did you also check whether the socket file exists at the given location?

Yes, it exists.  I added it to the description.
